# Find the length of a number's "base-jumping" path

Tags: code-golf, integer, base-conversion

Consider a positive integer `N` written in base `b`. A sequence is generated from this number by finding the largest digit `d` in the expansion of `N` and writing `N` in base `d+1`, repeating until the base the number is written in can be decreased no further. For example, the sequence generated by `346 (10)` in starting base 16 has length 6: `15A (16) = 295 (11) = 346 (10) = 1003 (7) = 11122 (4) = 110211 (3)`. Note that the next term in the sequence would be in base 3 again, which is invalid since the base does not decrease.

The goal of this code golf challenge is to write a program/function that takes two inputs (a decimal integer and a starting base - order doesn't matter and the two numbers must be integers) and outputs the length of the sequence generated according to the above rules.

Some test cases:

```
(24, 4) = 2
(19, 10) = 1
(346, 16) = 6
(7557, 97) = 20
```

Comment: Isn't `(7557, 97) = 20`? (`[97, 89, 85, 78, 70, 68, 44, 40, 38, 34, 19, 18, 16, 14, 12, 10, 8, 7, 5, 3]`)

Comment: Suggested test case: (15*256+1,4)

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
b@Ṁ‘ɗƬL
```

A dyadic Link accepting `b` on the left and `N` on the right which yields the sequence length.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/J4eHOhkcNM05OP7bG5////4Zm/41NzAA)**

#### How?

```
b@Ṁ‘ɗƬL - Link: b; N
     Ƭ  - Collect up until no longer unique, applying:
    ɗ   -   last three links as a dyad - i.e. f(X[initially b], N):
 @      -     with swapped arguments:
b       -       convert (N) to base (X)
  Ṁ     -     maximum
   ‘    -     incremented
      L - length
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 44 bytes

```ruby
->n,b{r=1;r+=1while b>b=n.digits(b).max+1;r}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y5PJ6m6yNbQukjb1rA8IzMnVSHJLsk2Ty8lMz2zpFgjSVMvN7FCGyhf@79AIS3ayETHJJYLxDK01DE0gDCNTcx0DM0gbHNTU3MdS/PY/wA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 67 bytes

edit: bug fix

```python
S=lambda n,b,p=0:p-b and S(n,max(n/b**x%b for x in range(n))+1,b)+1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYzLCsMgEEX3/YrZFNROabU@aCFf4Rc4pI9AMxHJwny9dVPI5sA9cE/e1s/CprU4fNNMYwJGwjxcH/lMkHiEKBjnVAVfSKl6JHgtBSpMDCXx@ylYypNG6mi5TLyKKIxFK@XhP2/Wo/Y7EZwLeA87o50yzvdO/7Uf)

Explanation:

```python
def S(Nr, Base, PrevBase=0):
    if Base != PrevBase:     # break recursion if Base repeats
        # find maximum digit in current base
        M=max([ (Nr//Base**x) % Base for x in range(Nr)])
        # return number of remaining steps plus one
        return 1 + S(Nr,M+1,Base)
    return 0
```

Comment: Fails for `15*256+1,4` (gives 2 instead of 1)

Comment: @Kritixi Lithos thanks, the problem is fixed now. Luckily runtime doesn't matter for code golf.

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup><s>40</s></sup> 37 bytes

```
[:<:@#(h,])^:([>h=.1+[:>./#.inv)/^:a:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/o61srByUNTJ0YjXjrDSi7TJs9Qy1o63s9PSV9TLzyjT146wSrf5rcilwpSZn5CuYKdgqpCkYmikYm5hBRIzAIiYKRiYQviFEhYGCoSVUgQFYxNJcwdzU1Pw/AA)

*-3 bytes thanks to Galen Ivanov*

Comment: Why not make it an [oneliner](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/o61srByUNTJ0YjXjrDSi7TJs9Qy1o63s9PSV9TLzyjT146wSrf5rcilwpSZn5CuYKdgqpCkYmikYm5hBRIzAIiYKRiYQviFEhYGCoSVUgQFYxNJcwdzU1Pw/AA)

Comment: Indeed.  Thanks Galen.

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), <s>46</s> 44 bytes

```julia
N*b=(d=max(digits(N,base=b)...)+1)==b||N*d+1
```

This uses a recursive approach together with the short-circuit operator `||` and makes use of the fact that Julia promotes booleans to integers under addition, so `true + 1 == 2`. This also overwrites the `*` operator, which you wouldn't normally do, but this lets me write `f(N,d)` infix as `N*d` to save 3 bytes.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/308ryVYjxTY3sUIjJTM9s6RYw08nKbE41TZJU09PT1PbUNPWNqmmxk8rRdvwv0NxRn65gpaGkYmOgokmF4xraKmjYGigqaCsUFJUmqpga6tgCJczNjEDSpohFJubmprrKFiaa/4HAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>22</s> <s>19</s> 14 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
{aU=VìU rÔÄ}f1
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=e2FVPVbsVSBy1MR9ZjE&input=NAoyNA)

Takes input as base,number

```
{           }f1     repeat until function return false  starting with 1, increment in 
 a                  difference between 1st input U and..
  U=                U, which is assigned..
    VìU             2nd input V to base U
        rÔ          reduced to max
          Ä         add 1
```

Saved 5 thanks to @Shaggy suggestion to use reduce to max instead of sort, plus using counter of *f()* instead of manually count using T

Comment: [14 bytes](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=e2FVPVbsVSBy1MR9ZjE&input=NAoyNA)?

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 24 bytes

```
ＮθＮηＷ∧⊞Ｏυη⁻⊖η⌈↨θη≧⁻ιηＩＬυ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYu9DoJAEIR7nuLKJcHSEEOF2pj4Q3yDEzbsJtwBd7vq259A5XTfzHwt2dCOdkjp4ieVu7oXBpjzKvtnWvhDPKCB2nfQaKTHhMHKGEALQ3lhbuw1whnbgA69YAdba7/s1MHRRoR5fa5Z6qmOkXv/5J4ENrcwvO5V1gT2AicbBa7oeyHQxalSKvf7MjuUafcefg) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
ＮθＮη
```

Input `N` and `b`.

```
Ｗ∧⊞Ｏυη⁻⊖η⌈↨θη
```

Push `b` to the predefined empty list to build up the sequence, then convert `N` to base `b`, and subtract the largest resulting digit from `b-1`. Repeat until this is zero.

```
≧⁻ιη
```

Calculate the new base.

```
ＩＬυ
```

Output the length of the sequence. (-1 byte to output the sequence itself.)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 87 bytes

```python
h=lambda n,b:n>=b and max(n%b,h(n/b,b))or n
f=lambda n,b,c=0:b!=c and f(n,h(n,b)+1,b)+1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7NCsIwEITveYr1IKa6YNPftBBfRDw0LaUFu4p40KevkwjiYZIvm5ll7u/ndJNsXSd37RY/dCTsWzk5T50MtHQvLVvPk5ajZ58ktweJGv@83Lu09RvXR/@oJXjhPJh4rPfHLE@adF2WNVNTJ@o7scXeNgdr1LnB3DZQyVRbKGWqcBcFBM7BOdjAY8CmgsI7g/AfIkwI5xc1hn7saRY66ywsSFjHYArIixCtQL82l1bRt1BszTt32vEYef0A)

Comment: `and f(...)+1` ~> `and-~f(...=` would save a byte. `!=` ~> `-` would save another.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 60 bytes

Takes input as `(n)(b)`.

```javascript
n=>g=b=>(x=(h=n=>n&&Math.max(n%b,h(n/b|0)))(n)+1)<b?1+g(x):1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XcxBDoIwEIXhvadgI5kJSikCDcbiCTxEi1AwODVCDAvvXouu5O3@fMm7qZca62f/mPZkr41rpSNZGallBbOETvqiMLyoqYvvagba6l0HxPQ7QUQgjDie9JlHBmY8cldbGu3QxIM10EKaIWSIwTLGgnTzz7xE4MnPPfMVH7LCe/F1z8WKRZ4LhFIsvpwn7gM)

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 83 bytes

```cs
x=>y=>{int g=y,t=0;for(;x>(x=new int[32].Max(l=>g-(g/=x)*x)+1);t++,g=y);return++t;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYsxC8IwEEZ3f0XHO9OqtdLlvBuddHYQBwlJCEiENMUU8bfHTA4fvMfj01OnJ19Oc9BHH1L7hzoRyyWzLCyfqo3jpU28I/uKQFkgczDvppbbsL9vLo8MTxbXgdtyxnVG1SMlpdr6Q4omzTEolehbaHWNPpmzDwYs9CPCcBgRqfwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 22 bytes

```
[:#([:>./1+#.inv~)^:a:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/o62UNaKt7PT0DbWV9TLzyuo046wSrf5rcqUmZ@QrmCnYKhibmCmkKRiaQUSMgCJGJkABEwjfEMg3tAQpMIAqMACKmJuamgPFLM3/AwA)

Simplified version of [Jonah's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/196515/78410).

#### How it works

```
[:#([:>./1+#.inv~)^:a:  Left: number N, Right: initial base B
   (             )^:a:  Collect all intermediate values up to fixpoint:
           #.inv~         Compute digits of N in base B
         1+               Increment
    [:>./                 Max; this becomes the new value of B
[:#                     Length of the result
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>8</s> 7 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
Δвà>¼}¾
```

-1 byte thanks to *@Grimmy*.

Start-base \$b\$ as first input; number \$N\$ as second input.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3JQLmw4vsDu0p/bQvv//Dc24jE3MAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@koGunoGRfeWhNaML/c1Miii9sOrzA7tCe2kP7/uvoHdr6PzrayETHJFZHIdrQUsfQAMQwNjHTMTQDscxNTc11LM1jYwE).

**Explanation:**

```python
Δ     # Loop until the top of the stack no longer changes:
 в    #  Convert the (implicit) input-integer N to (implicit) input-base b as list
  à   #  Pop the list and push the maximum
   >  #  Increase it by 1 (which will be the new base b for the next iteration,
      #                    with the same (implicit) input-integer N)
 ¼    #  And in every loop-iteration: increase the counter_variable by 1
}¾    # After the loop: push the counter_variable
      # (after which it is output implicitly as result)
```

Comment: [No need to repeat the `в`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3JQLmw4vsDu0p/bQvv//Lc25zE1NzQE). Alternative 7: `Δвà>}N>`.

Comment: @Grimmy Ah, of course. And I knew about that alternative. I actually had that one in mind as well, but liked this one more (especially because it also works in the legacy version and I prefer to keep the loop-index inside the loop when using it - if I have a choice like here). Thanks for the -1, though

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://bitbucket.org/ngn/k), 18 bytes

```
{#{1+|/y\:x}[x]\y}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/z/Nqlq52lC7Rr8yxqqiNroiNqay9n9atLmpqXmsgqX5fwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 89 bytes

```
func[n b][k: 0 until[k: k + 1 m: n t: 1 until[t: max t m % b 1 > m: m / b]b = b: 1 + t]k]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY3LCsIwFAX3fsUQEJQKNtoHLdSPcBuyaNoGS02UkoJ/X1PdDfecM3ce@vU@9ErvbM1qF98pj9FqqklZfBifG04kSFyNJ9SR/kFE134IOPaYeL5tFcc5CgwNZqsmBD3p1b7moe0e/OyoS0aGrJAp16xAFpR5XlKVMXvPow9KHET8Jk4imsWRRmDZtnr9Ag)

Answer (score 0):

## MIT-Scheme, 117 bytes

```
(define(g n r)(if(= n 0)0(max(modulo n r)(g(quotient n r)r))))
(define(f n r)(if(=(+(g n r)1)r)1(1+(f n(1+(g n r))))))
```

(newline added for readability)

`g` is a helper function that computes the maximum digit of the number in a radix, and `f` is the main function.

Answer (score 0):

## Haskell, 104 bytes

```
i=iterate
d n b=1+maximum(take(n+1)$snd<$>i((`divMod`b).fst)(n,0))
u(a:b:c)|a==b=1|2>1=1+u(b:c)
(u.).i.d
```

Haskell has no base conversion function. So I have to implement it normally.

`snd<$>i((`divMod`b).fst)(n,0)` returns an infinite list with zero as the first element, followed by represented by the representation of n at base b, followed by infinite number of zeros. (`((`divMod`b).fst)(0,0)` returns `(0,0)`)

I just iterate function d until the value stopped changing and count the number of iteration. (In haskell, you do that by `iterate`ing the function infinitely and take only the first few elements)